# how to use html inside php while loop

Tags: php, mysql

I have user information coming from database on a profile page using a `while` loop. I want to be able to write stuff like this, $username's profile. I can't seem to figure it out. Here is my code.

```
<?php
//open database connection
include 'page-start.php';
include 'core/init.php';
?>
<?php
$myQuery = ("SELECT user_id, username, profile, city FROM `users` WHERE user_id = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['ID']) . "' ") or die(mysql_error());

    //run query
$result = $con->query($myQuery);
if (!$result) die('Query error: ' . mysqli_error($result));

if($result === FALSE) {
die(mysql_error()); // TODO: better error handling
} ?>

<?php require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/studentsupport/defines.php'; ?>



    <?php include_once("head.php");
            while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
            {

        echo '<div class="sixteen columns" id="user-profile">';

                    echo'<h2 class="username"> ' . $row['username'] . '  </h2> ';//bob's Profile
                echo'<p>' . $row['city'] . '</p>'; //city: london

                    echo '<div class="eight columns" id="user-profile-img">';

                    echo'<img src="'. $row['profile'] . '"/>';

        echo '</div>';
                echo '</div>';
}
            ?>
```

edit: sorry I didn't explain it very well.

I want to be able to have some information come from the database and some information just as standard html for example:

```
<p><?php echo $username; ?>'s profile </p>
<p>city: <?php echo $city; ?> </p>
```

Comment: Where is your problem? This seems ok

Comment: What sort of error are you getting?  Because assuming "head.php" contains all the correct connection info, this should work.

Comment: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string concatenation to accomplish this because you will probably create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). **DO NOT** use `mysql_real_escape_string` when using `mysqli`, they are totally different libraries and not interchangeable.

Comment: I am fairly new to php/sql, so I don't really understand what you mean. Most of this stuff was from following tutorials. I am aware of injection but I am not too woried about that at the moment as my project is for univeristy and not going online. I also havn't got much time left. I am going to learn more about security when I finish and have more time.

Answer (score -1):

During each loop in the while, $row['username'] will have a username.

If you want to be able to get all the usernames later, add the following:

```
$users[] = $row['username'];
```

Now, Everywhere in your script $users[0] will have the 1st username, $users[1] will have the second, etc.

Comment: I think this should be a comment, this is just an add to his issue, but not an answer on his exact question I think.

Comment: @Xatenev: He wants to be able to write $userename's profile. That's exactly what I'm explaining here.

Comment: Mhm okay, maybe I am understanding his question wrong. Sorry!

Answer (score -1):

This may do it.

```
<?php include_once("head.php");
    while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    { ?>
       <div class="sixteen columns" id="user-profile">
            <h2 class="username"><?php echo $row['username']; ?></h2>
           <p><?php echo $row['city']; ?></p>
           <div class="eight columns" id="user-profile-img">
               <img src="<?php echo $row['profile']; ?>"/>
            </div>
        </div>
 <? }     ?>
```

Comment: His code is working, It won't change anything, to just split PHP and HTML.

Comment: And it makes things far more complicated to read and understand too.

Comment: thats not an opinion. His code is working. This one will probably too. That is no solution to his problem.

Comment: it should work either way... the given information is not enough to debug. if he has a data structure that is not right that might be it. is the db connecting? does the data exists for every column and row... either way would work to display a loop which is why i wrote down a possible answer. what is your solution? what's in the head.php?

Comment: sorry guys i didn't explain it very well. (lack of sleep) my code works I just want to be able to extract the selected users profile information with php but i also want to use html as well. I have edited the question and given a better example

Comment: what does your query and/or data structure look like?

Comment: Are you saying you want user_id's that are =''? That is feeling incomplete... SELECT user_id, username, profile, city FROM `users` WHERE user_id = '"

SELECT user_id, username, profile, city FROM `users`

Comment: shouldn't the query just be  SELECT user_id, username, profile, city FROM users

??

Answer (score -1):

If you are beginner than i wil say You should use easy method now it seems okay

like You make Whole page of profile like you want

like

then you can Take your data in Variables in `while Loop` like that

```
    while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
   {
     $profile = $row['profile'];
      $name = $row['name'];//you can take as many variables as you want 
     $city = $row['city'];
    }
```

then you can use these variables in html simply

```
<div class="sixteen columns" id="user-profile">

                   <h2 class="username"><?php echo $name; ?> </h2>

</div>
```

start like that next step like above will get easy to u :)

Comment: This will not work, like this you will save the LAST user in the database into $profile and $name. This has to look like $profile[] = and $name[] = ... (Explained in LPChip's Answer)

Comment: Your code will only show the last username and profile in a database. If there are more he has no idea how it should work. Which is why I added an array into my solution.

Comment: he wrote in his question it is for A USER profile not like admin page